# R won't find objects

Tags: r

I have an R program from my school that uses a lot of .r and .rd files (the program is an example, tested to work on R 3.5.3, which is what I compiled from source on Zorin OS 15.1, everything updated.) for basketball data science. All these files come from BasketballAnalyzeR. I put all the .r and .rd files on the same directory as the example program that uses them, but when I run the program it throws a lot of errors that say 'Object not found', whereas these objects are on the external .r and .rd files. How can I fix this? Some of those files have commands that start with \ is that a problem? Also, I see comments that say stuff like `@export` which are highlighted in blue, is that also a problem? Sorry, I am new to R.

Comment: Maybe. Those two examples you gave are not recognisable R commands. Trying to run the file may still work if those "unknown" commands are just comments that have no effect on other vital commands. A comment in R is achieved using the hash symbol `#`.

Comment: Another common error when sharing R command files is that you may need to change the R working directory if external data files are required. If you see a `setwd ()` command near the top of the file, you may need to change this to your own directory.

Comment: @Edward It normally didn't have a setwd() command but I added one on my own. That seems to change the working directory OK. I do see syntax errors on the \ characters (the interpreter tells me that) but since it was tested with these exact same files and the exact same program, how can it not work on my computer? The program with the files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i4yn4sP6hUvt6UtBiU-6hOUfKtd5XNRU

Comment: I see some external (not standard R) libraries that are loaded. You'll need to install these. For example, in the BasketBall Data Science R file, you'll need to install the CINNA, lsr and other libraries.

Comment: @Edward Yes RStudio told me to install them for me (CINNA, jpeg, plotly and a few others if I recall correctly) and it installed them OK with no errors. I still can't run it.

Comment: Sorry - I'm having difficulty installing the BasketballAnalyzeR from GitHub. I can't think of any other reason for the commands not to run. I did try to run the BasketBall Data Science R file but couldn't get past the following at line #5.  `> sapply(files.sources, source)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : assistnet.Rd:3:1: unexpected input
2: # Please edit documentation in R/assistnet.R`

Comment: @Edward Yes that is EXACTLY my error, with the \. If I remove all the \ it still doesn't work. You don't need to get BasketballAnalyzeR from GitHub, all the files there are straight from its zip.

Comment: But I needed to install that package. It wasn't in the zip file (or was it?). And you shouldn't edit those .Rd files. They are R documentation files, not R command files.

Comment: How can I install it? It wasn't in the zip. I learnt I shouldn't edit those .Rd files later. Again how can I install the BasketballAnalyzeR package? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Edward Never mind I found how to install it. Thanks A LOT for your help! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Edward I am the author of BasketballAnalyzeR. See this link https://bdsports.unibs.it/basketballanalyzer for details on the installation and for the email address to get assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all I needed to do was install the package instead of using the .R and .Rd files on my working directory.

Comment: Hi. To install `BasketballAnalyzeR` from GitHub, use: `install.packages("remotes")` followed by `remotes::install_github("sndmrc/BasketballAnalyzeR")`. See: https://bdsports.unibs.it/basketballanalyzer/

Comment: `BasketballAnalyzeR` can also be installed from CRAN using `install.packages("BasketballAnalyzeR")`